# Using a View 'repository'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to create a view such that when it is run via a schedule, it only returns rows that have not been in any previous selects of that view? Coming from other systems I would see this as a repository to store results when the schedule is run, then exclude anything in the repository on subsequent runs. For MSSQL though, I imagine there are more clever ways of tackling this issue.

Comment: A view is just a query that get's executed, it has no knowledge of anything it showed before, maybe you could do it in a stored procedure which could write in a seperate table the last ID or some date column that it returned

Comment: You'll either need to have a date (and time) column you can filter on, or you'll need to have stored the unique identifier of the rows you saw before *somewhere* so you can exclude them.

Comment: I need to create a view to data that only returns rows that were not present the last time the view was run.

Comment: A view just encapsulates a SELECT query. Think about how you would solve the problem with a query.

Comment: You appear to have some misconceptions about views - a view is not run or executed.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. record the date and time when you make run the query and then run

```
select * from myView where dateTimeColumn > date_and_time_when_last_run;
```

2. use a stored procedure which notes the last record retrieved

Answer (score 1):

This not a "View" but you can use a `flag` to denote 'read', `OUTPUT` clause to return the columns to simulate what you want.

```
-- sample table
create table tbl
(
    ID int identity,
    flag bit default 0,
    DT datetime
);

-- insert 2 rows of sample data
insert into tbl(DT) values
(getdate()),
(getdate());

-- update the table set the flag and OUTPUT the columns
update tbl
set    flag = 1
output inserted.ID, inserted.DT
where  flag = 0;
```

Result:

| ID | DT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-30 13:04:47.860 |
| 2 | 2022-05-30 13:04:47.860 |

```
-- insert 3 more rows
insert into tbl(DT) values
(getdate()),
(getdate());

update tbl
set    flag = 1
output inserted.ID, inserted.DT
where  flag = 0;
```

Result:

| ID | DT |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-05-30 13:04:47.877 |
| 4 | 2022-05-30 13:04:47.877 |
| 5 | 2022-05-30 13:04:47.877 |
| 6 | 2022-05-30 13:04:47.877 |